# How can I send mail with SMTP and see the mail in the Outlook outbox?

Tags: outlook, smtp, exchange-server

We have a new Exchange server and use SMTP to send mails over it. This works so far, but we have no idea how the SMTP mail can be configured so that the outbox in Outlook 2003 of the sender account shows this mail. Is this only possible using MAPI or other mail client protocols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, email sent via SMTP will not be stored in the Exchange database. The simple way to work around it would be to automatically BCC the sender on any email sent via SMTP. It wouldn't be perfect as it would look like an incoming email, but at least the information would be there.
There might be addon products that you could buy that would listen in on any SMTP traffic and automatically create "sent items".

But the best solution would be something like `Exchange Web Services`, `CDO` or `MAPI` (depending on what your needs are and what software versions you're using).

Answer (score 2):

If the accounts are IMAP accounts, you can use that to put the mail into the Sent folder.  Otherwise, you'll have to use the Microsoft protocols like MAPI.

Comment: So I need SMTP and IMAP support in the application which sends the mail, SMTP to transfer the message and IMAP to put the mail in the outbox?

Comment: That's correct; when you send a message with e.g. Thunderbird, it will both dispatch the message via SMTP and store a copy for the user via IMAP.